# Deserialize Custom Collection with abstract Class Content

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

i have the following Problem:

System:

```
public class System {
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = MyDeserializer.class)
    ObservableList<AClass> aClassList;
}
```

AClass:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "dataType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubA.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubB.class)
 })
public abstract class AClass{
}
```

SubA:

```
public class SubA extends AClass{
    public SubA(String name) {
    }
}
```

SubB:

```
public class SubB extends AClass{
    public SubB(String name) {
    }
}
```

MyDeserializer:

```
public class MyDeserializer implements Converter<List<AClass>, ObservableList<AClass>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableList<AClass> convert(List<AClass> celestialBodyList) {
        return FXCollections.observableList(celestialBodyList);
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, AClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructCollectionType(ObservableList.class, AClass.class);
    }
}
```

When i try to deserialize the System class i get following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class javafx.collections.ObservableList, contains [simple type, class AClass]]
```

As you can see Jackson cannot find a deserializer even though i defined one via an Annotation.

Hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? From which package `JsonDeserialize` class comes from? I tried it for version [2.9.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8) and it works.

Comment: could you provide your objectMapper? I guess you forgot to add the deserializer to your module : module.addDeerializer(System .class, new MyDeserializer ());

Comment: @PierreGUILLAUME The objectMapper is out of reach for me, thats why i use the Annotation style syntax

Comment: @MichałZiober we use 2.9.8 with the JsonDeserializer out of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize

Comment: @laubed, I ran your example and it works for me with simple `POJO`. Maybe your model is complicated than what you have shown. Try to share the whole model and `JSON` payload which does not work for you.